# sdaps installation give pycairo location error

Tags: python, pycairo

I am trying to install sdaps but when i run setup.py install command it gives me following error:

```
kashif@crunchbang:~/sdaps-1.0.5$ python setup.py install
Package pycairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pycairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pycairo' found
```

i tried to fix this by installing

```
kashif@crunchbang:~/sdaps-1.0.5$ sudo apt-get install python-cairo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-cairo is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 148 not upgraded.
```

but again the same problem persists:

```
kashif@crunchbang:~/sdaps-1.0.5$ python setup.py install
Package pycairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pycairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pycairo' found
```

Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: Did you install all of the dependencies? http://sdaps.org/Documentation/Dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the following Ubuntu/Debian package dependencies before continuing:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra python-cairo-dev libtiff5-dev \
libcairo2-dev libglib2.0-dev python2.7-dev python-zbar python-gi \
python-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0 pdftk python-pypdf python-reportlab \
python-imaging
```

*Source: http://sdaps.org/Documentation/Dependencies*

Comment: Thanks Adam, it worked, only python-cairo-dev dependency was missing, i fix it by installing: